# データフレームで辞書のkeyと一致した要素のみそのvalueを出す

Tags: python, pandas

以前質問に答えていただき、リストの要素が辞書のkeyと一致したときにそのvalueを出す関数を以下のように作れました。これをデータフレームでおこなうにはどうすればいいでしょうか？どうしてもvalueを出せません。どうか教えていただけないでしょうか。

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
fruitnames = ["Apple", "Grape","Orange"]
fruitnumbers = {"Grape":2,"Strawberry":20,"Apple":10,"Orange":40}
def fruitcode():
    for key, value in fruitnumbers.items():
        for fruitname in fruitnames:
            if key == fruitname:
                print(fruitname, fruitnumbers[fruitname])

fruitcode()
```

出力結果

```
Grape 2
Apple 10
Orange 40
```

これをデータフレームでもできないでしょうか？

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Fruit', 'FruitNumber'])
df['Fruit'] = fruitnames
df
```

とすると、出力結果は

```
    Fruit   FruitNumber
0   Apple   NaN
1   Grape   NaN
2   Orange  NaN
```

となり、さらに

```
for key, value in fruitnumbers.items():
    if key == df['Fruit']:
        df['FruitNumber'] = fruitnumbers[df.Fruit]
    else:
        df['FruitNumber'] = 'None'
```

を加えるとValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().とでてしまいます。理想は

```
    Fruit   FruitNumber
0   Apple   10
1   Grape   2
2   Orange  40
```

です。どうぞよろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

こうゆうことですか？

```
import pandas as pd

fruitnames = pd.Series(["Apple", "Grape","Orange"], name='Fruit')
fruitnumbers = pd.Series({"Grape":2,"Strawberry":20,"Apple":10,"Orange":40}, name='FruitNumber')

# 結果がSeriesでよければ
ret = fruitnumbers[fruitnumbers.index.isin(fruitnames)]
print(ret)
# Apple     10
# Grape      2
# Orange    40
# Name: FruitNumber, dtype: int64

# 結果がDataFrameでなければならないのであれば変換
ret_df = ret.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'Fruit'})
print(ret_df)
#     Fruit  FruitNumber
# 0   Apple           10
# 1   Grape            2
# 2  Orange           40
```